# WPF Listbox Grouping Header Not Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a CollectionViewSource, It is grouped by a Created proprty in an ObservableCollection.  The Grouping works within the listbox with the exception to i cannot get the Header text to display the created date.

The CollectionViewSource is below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TaskListColSource" Source="{Binding Path=TaskItems}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Created" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Created" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</Window.Resources>
```

My Listbox GroupStyle is below:

```
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Foreground="White">
                                        <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:TaskItem}">
                                                <TextBlock  x:Name="asdf" Text="{Binding Created}" Foreground="White"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>

                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

Could anyone possibly help me with displaying the created date within the relevant Textblock?

I am binding the listbox in the following way:

```
<ListBox x:Name="TaskListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TaskListColSource}}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `Header` for your Expander like this:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True" Foreground="White" 
          Header="{Binding}">
</Expander>
```

The implicit `DataContext` in each `GroupItem` is each data item. So the `Header` should be set to each data item (via `{Binding}`). The `HeaderTemplate` has implicit `DataContext` as its `Header` but you has not assigned anything for it.

**Edit**:

If you want some StringFormat, why not set it inside `TextBlock` (let the `Header` unchanged):

```
 <TextBlock  x:Name="asdf" Text="{Binding Created, StringFormat=dd MMM yy, ConverterCulture=en-GB}" Foreground="White"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that works, however Created is a DateTime.  it displays it in the US format i am trying to get it into a more UK format.  i know this is slightly off piste but do you know how i can achieve this?


                                        <Expander Header="{Binding ., StringFormat='{}{dd MMM YY}', ConverterCulture=en-GB}" IsExpanded="True" Foreground="White">
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>

Comment: @ChrisThomas see my edit, you should do that on the `TextBlock`. The `Header` should be kept unchanged.

Comment: where do i use the TextBlock, i have tried to set it within the HeaderTemplate but it requires me to set a DataTemplate then and if i use a similar structure to the one i originally posted im back to a blank header.

Comment: @ChrisThomas the `TextBlock` is already yours (did you not see its Name `asdf`?). It's inside the `HeaderTemplate`'s `DataTemplate`.

Comment: when i try to set the binding as you have outlined i get blank/null text being displayed :(  in the <Header> tag i have Header="{Binding}" and then i have the textbox as you have outlined.

Comment: @ChrisThomas see my edit, the `StringFormat` was used wrong (copied from yours). It should not have any `{...}`, we use `{}` only for `MultiBinding` or when we want to repeat the result, in `Binding` there is just 1 position.

Comment: i have tried that and am still getting no text being displayed, there is a cannot resolve symbol error on the Created as well.  i have also tried putting single quotes around the string format as well.

Comment: @ChrisThomas it's strange that it works on my side, the stringformat should be `dd MMM yy`. You can try removing `StringFormat` (as before) to see if it's still working. If it still works then the StringFormat after added should also work. Don't try adding any quotes, it won't work that way.

Comment: Hi,  i managed to get it to work by using Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat=dd MMM yy, ConverterCulture=en-GB}"   thank you so much for your help with this, i dont think i would of gotten close to sorting it without your assistance!